# unix shell: how to escapte a hidden directory name "."

Tags: shell, unix

I am using AIX version 6.1.0.0.  I have a hiden directory name like ".sh".  When I place the directory name into a variable, I always get a cannot find file error.

```
file_dir=/opt/.sh/scripts
$file_dir/Find_files.sh $file_dir/file_name
```

Errors:  cat: 0652-050 Cannot open "file_name".  A file or directory in the path name does not exist.

I believe the issue is that hidden directory name ".sh".  How can I go around this issue?

Comment: Show output of `stat /opt/.sh`, `ls -als /opt/.sh`, `stat /opt/.sh/scripts/`, `ls -als /opt/.sh/scripts/`, `id`

Comment: Remember that a directory should be readable & executable to be part of a file path

Comment: Read [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html); the issue is *not* about hidden directory (they matter for [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) only)

Comment: Your script is broken. More info could be given if you quoted the script.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the permissions on the file, directory, subdirs and which user your using its hard to be a 100% sure. But related information about this error states the following:

```
Possible Causes
1. This error message may be displayed during a backup operation.
2. The system looked for a file that either does not exist or was specified incorrectly.
3. The system looked for a file for which you do not have write permission.
```

Personally I think its a permission issue with your directory or subdir, so make sure you have the correct access or ownership.